# stringstream not working with integer types in native library function called through managed C# code

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, iostream, libstdc++

I know that the information below might be insufficient, but I could really use some help, at least what to check in order to better understand the problem. This is really weird and I don't know how to approach it.

I am trying to run third party native code that uses `stringstream` for some purposes. There is `extern C` linkage convention specified. The library is complex and links to other libraries, has both C and C++ code.

This code is being called, on Linux (Ubuntu 18.04), from a C# through `dlopen` and `dlsym`.

Now the tricky part. When I build the C# Console Application and run it, everything works correctly. When I use the same native libraries and dlls and run everything from Unity3D, there is a crash. Same native code is running (I guess something is different with the calling context/environments).

I've tracked the crash to stringstreams "not working" in the Unity3D case. Same code is called in native library in both cases.

The minimal code:

```
    std::stringstream ss;
    int a = 5;
    ss << a;
    std::string s1 = ss.str();
    fprintf(stderr, "STREAM: %s\n", s1.c_str());
```

`.Net` console application outputs `STREAM 5`
*Unity3D* outputs `STREAM`

Also, *goodbit* is set in the good case and *badbit* is set in the bad case (even right after construction).

Strings work correctly with the stream.

I've looked into `dlopen` flags and GCC `ABI flag`, this doesn't help. I also investigated `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and other env variables in both cases. It's also not about `fprintf`.

Edit:
I determined that many locale standard facets are not present in the bad case (and are ok in the good one), which causes streams to fail on ints (and other types). I can't create a locale with them, and locale combine doesn't work. But why are the locale facets missing? This issue is also on another machine.

Comment: possibly a locale issue?

Comment: The locales were different, but I just checked, making them the same. It doesn't change the bug. This is an issue with int type, so I would imagine locale is not important

Comment: The locale is used to convert the integer to a string, if there is something wrong with the locale output stream operators can fail

Comment: I am trying to determine why this could be present in the case. Any clues? I am looking into facets now. What would be the best way to check for int type?

Comment: So.. Indeed there is problem - and thank you for a clue. I still have no idea how to fix it, but I know that that multiple facets are missing (actually, only two are present) in the Unity3D run as opposed to the working one.